# Android 2.0: How do I receive a list of groups a known contact belongs to?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-2.0-eclair

I've written my application to find the contact, if one exists, for an incoming phone call.

I want to take action if that contact belongs to one or more flagged groups.
However I cannot find a link between the contact and group membership content providers.

How do I query group membership?

Comment: how you solved this problem.please send me the code in jagadevsritam@gmail.com